# Change text color in adapter using custom layout with tab layout fragment

Tags: android

Good Day to all, In this application, need to change text color on menu item click. Textview is in custom row layout which inflated by adapter and adapter set in a fragment Tab layout. On menu item, click needs to change text color of listview whole listview. On normal application, its work fine but on a fragment, it gives error "Adaptor.setTextColor(int)' on a null object reference" If anyone can give help. Thank you

MainActivity.java

```
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
 private ViewPager mViewPager;
   NewsAdaptor adaptor;

protected void onCreate ( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(10);
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));
}


  @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu ( Menu menu ) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@SuppressLint("ResourceType")
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected ( MenuItem item ) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.chagecolor) {
        adaptor.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        adaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

newsApapter.java

```
public class NewsAdaptor extends BaseAdapter {
TextView tvtitle;
private int color;
Context context;

public NewsAdaptor ( Context context, ArrayList <NewsItem> newsList ) {
    this.context = context;
    this.newsList = newsList;
    this.color = Color.RED;
}

ArrayList<NewsItem> newsList;

@Override
public int getCount () {

    return newsList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem ( int position ) {
    return newsList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId ( int position ) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView ( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) {
    if (convertView == null){
        convertView=View.inflate(context, R.layout.newsitemlist_layout,null);
    }
    NewsItem currentNews = newsList.get(position);
    tvtitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1id);
    tvtitle.setText(currentNews.getTitle());
    tvtitle.setTextColor(color);
    return convertView;
}
public void setTextColor(int color) {
    this.color = color;

}
```

}

Now it in a fragment which whare adapter is implemented

NEwsFragment.java

```
public class TRADE extends Fragment {


public TRADE () {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
ArrayList<NewsItem> newsItemsList;

ListView ali;
NewsAdaptor adapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView ( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                           Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_trade, container, false);
      newsItemsList = new ArrayList<>();
      ali = (ListView)view. findViewById(R.id.listtrade);
       RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
      StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest("https://urdu.geo.tv/rss/1/3", new Response.Listener <String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse ( String response ) {
            Document document = Jsoup.parse(response);
            Elements itemElements = document.getElementsByTag("item");
            for (int i = 0; i < itemElements.size(); i++) {
                Element item = itemElements.get(i);
                String title = rem(item.child(0).text());

                NewsItem news = new NewsItem();
                news.title = title;
                newsItemsList.add(news);
            }
            adapter = new NewsAdaptor(getContext(), newsItemsList);
            ali.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse ( VolleyError error ) {


        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

newsitemlist_layout.xml

```
   <RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1id"
    android:layout_width="237dp"
    android:layout_height="83dp"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/pubDateid"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/pubDateid"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="News TITLE"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way
add green color in color.xml
and try this way

```
@SuppressLint("ResourceType")
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected ( MenuItem item ) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.chagecolor) {
        adaptor.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.green));
        adaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: replace with this or getApplicationContext()

Answer (score 0):

Your **adaptor** variable from **MainActivity** and **Fragment** is different, so **adaptor** in your **MainActivity** hasn't been defined yet. Thus you are getting nullPointerException. I think you need to redesign your code or try implementing this on your **Fragment** class.

First,

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);   //Remember this line
}
```

Then,

```
 @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_frag_menu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Finally,

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected ( MenuItem item ) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.chagecolor) {
        adaptor.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        adaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: So how define adapter in mainactivity

Comment: If you define adapter from your mainactivity, you cannot use it inside your fragment and vice-versa. But you can communicate between them using interfaces. But looking at your code, it would be better and simpler to use adapter only from fragment.

Comment: :) You are welcome. And you can also thank me by upvoting this answer if it helped.

Comment: if need to change text color  in more fragment tab so how to notify adapter

Answer (score 0):

Your onOptionsItemSelected method(located on MainActivity) doesn't know about adaptor object's declaration since you didn't declare it on MainActivity. What you have to do is

1) Remove the onOptionsItemSelected code from your MainActivity.

2) Enable optionsmenu In your fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

3) Then inflate it:

```
 @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_frag_menu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

4) Then do something with onOptionsItemSelected callback:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item) {
    final int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.chagecolor) {
        adaptor.setTextColor(getResources.getColor(R.color.GREEN);
        adaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```